# Add Text Hint to Bootstrap Navbar Toggle Button on Mobile-View

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, mobile, user-experience

Some tests have shown that the "hamburger" button for collapsable menus on mobile devices are mysteries to users and I would like to add the word "Menu" next to my Bootstrap menu button as seen in mobile-view.

For further reading check out this article: 'The Hamburger is Bad for You': http://mor10.com/hamburger-bad/

Here is the basic Bootstrap Code:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <!-- Represents navbar collapsed menu on smaller screens -->
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <!-- 3 horizontal lines on small screen nav button -->
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

So, I'd like to add the word "MENU" next to the icon on mobile. I made a mockup of what I'm talking about but I don't have a high enough reputation on SO to post it.

Check it out here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dArg.jpg

- FYI this is a mockup, the actual Bootstrap page does not contain the MENU text or else I'd just look at the source.

If you could provide info on how to include is as (A) simply text next to the button & (B) as part of the button so it could be clicked that'd be awesome. Thanks in advance for your help with this solution!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess it would be the best to use fontawesome.

simply include the references to fontawesome (see http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) and then use the bars icon (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/bars/)

So your code would look sth. like that:

```
<head>
   [...]
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   [...]
</head>
<body>

[...]

<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <!-- Represents navbar collapsed menu on smaller screens -->
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu
</button>
```

If the Bars icon should be bigger, simply add `fa-lg` or any other class which can be found at http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/ to the icon

Comment: this is an elegant solution and I'm already using Font Awesome - perfect. Would just need to add some styling to the button. I'd still like to know how to put the word Menu outside of the button as an option.

Comment: i guesss sth. like a nested button could be a solution. but that wouldn't be that nice style. the outer button would link to nowhere, and you would have to remove some styles of the inner button (such as border, shadow etc...)

Comment: Nice idea, you can now also use glyphicon to show bars. I did this - 
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i> Links

Answer (score 13):

Another just css solution:

```
.navbar-toggle:before {
    content:"Menu";
    left:-50px;
    top:4px;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="button-label">Menu</span>
    <div class="button-bars">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </div>
</button>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-toggle .button-label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.button-bars {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this makes the whole navbar 8 pixeůs higher

Comment: I had to remove the line-height and then it was fine for me. Great!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but didn't feel like adding fontawesome.

Here is my solution (HTML and LESS):

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="button-label">Meny</span>
    <div class="button-hamburger">
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </div>
</button>
```

LESS:

```
button {

    .button-label {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding-right: 3px;
    }

    .button-hamburger {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;

        .icon-bar {
            background: #333;
        }
    }
}
.navbar-toggle {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

WARNING: I'v only tested this in lastest Chrome and IE 11. I do not have anything else set up atm.