# How to add menu text only in mobile using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu

check screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mYet.jpg

iam using the following bootstrap menu code.

I want to add text like 'MENU' in mobile only. how to do that?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">MENU 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">MENU 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="food.html">MENU 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="apparels.html">MENU 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Better solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744914/add-text-hint-to-bootstrap-navbar-toggle-button-on-mobile-view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show navbar only for mobile view use "visible-xs" class .

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default visible-xs">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <span class="Position">Menu</span>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">MENU 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">MENU 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="food.html">MENU 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="apparels.html">MENU 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

  @media (min-width: 320px) {
.Position
{
float: left !important;
margin-left: 69%;
margin-top: 12px;
font-size: 18px;
}
}
@media (min-width: 360px) {
.Position
{
float: left !important;
margin-left: 73%;
margin-top: 12px;
font-size: 18px;
}
}
```

Comment: Simply does not work and by that i mean it doesn't position well.  I found a better solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744914/add-text-hint-to-bootstrap-navbar-toggle-button-on-mobile-view